# How to put image to Progress View and make it moving with it

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, uiprogressview

I'm working on the air application and there I have a progress view. [How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOPKh.png)

So, I need to know, how it possible to add image to progress view and it will move together. Here is how it should look like: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1F5y.png)

I've tried something like this: progressView.trackImage = UIImage(named: "smallPlane")

Update:

*

```
func setupProgressView() {
    middleView.insertSubview(planeView, aboveSubview: progressView)
    let leadingConstraint = planeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressView.leadingAnchor)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        leadingConstraint,
        planeView.widthAnchor(equalToConstant: ),
        planeView.heightAnchor(equalToConstant: ),
        planeView.centerYAnchor(equalTo: progressView.centerYAnchor)
    )
    leadingConstraint.isActive = true
    leadingConstraint.constant = progressView.frame.width * CGFloat(progressView.progress)
    progressView.transform = progressView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 0.5)
}
```

- 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an `UIImageView` and change it’s position according to the progress. Let's say you have `someView`, which contains your progress view:

```
let planeView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "smallPlane"))
someView.insertSubview(planeView, aboveSubview: progressView)

// Don’t forget to store `leadingConstraint` somewhere.
let leadingConstraint = planeView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressView.leadingAnchor)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    leadingConstraint,
    planeView.widthAnchor(equalToConstant: <your_value>),
    planeView.heightAnchor(equalToConstant: <your_value>),
    planeView.centerYAnchor(equalTo: progressView.centerYAnchor)
])
```

Now you can change the `constant` of the `leadingConstraint` when you change the `progress` of `progressView` like that:

```
leadingConstraint.constant = progressView.frame.width * progress
```

Comment: I've put this code and get the plane under the progress view. Is it possible to put on progress view? Thank you

Comment: Then just add it in the same view as progress view

Comment: Not sure that I understand, I have this progress view inside view on the bottom

Comment: ok, I edited the answer a little bit

Comment: On the NSLayoutConstrains method I've go a lot of errors: Extra arguments at positions #2, #3, #4 in call, Cannot convert value of type 'NSLayoutConstraint' to expected argument type '[NSLayoutConstraint]', Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'widthAnchor(equalToConstant:)'

Comment: Check it out, this one should work

Comment: Don't understand what to do with constraint which you wrote

Comment: Please share your full code then I will show how it exactly it should be done

Comment: middleView.insertSubview(planeView, aboveSubview: progressView)
        let leadingConstraint = planeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressView.leadingAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            leadingConstraint,
            planeView.widthAnchor(equalToConstant: ),
            planeView.heightAnchor(equalToConstant: ),
            planeView.centerYAnchor(equalTo: progressView.centerYAnchor)
        )
        leadingConstraint.isActive = true
        leadingConstraint.constant = progressView.frame.width * CGFloat(progressView.progress)

Comment: Please edit your original question, don’t share it in the comments :)

Comment: I have the similar code as yours and got errors

Comment: Check, I've updated the question

Comment: sorry for long response. NSLayoutConstraint.activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) takes array as an argument. So just add [] for your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution, It'll definitely work for you

Step 1: Replace the ProcessView with UISlider

Step 2: UISlider provider the handle where you can set your desired image

```
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Image_Name"), for: .normal)
```

Step 3: If you want that user not able to move handle then put the below line

```
slider.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```